# Testing AWS Gateway with PostMan vs Chrome

Tags: amazon-web-services, cookies

I'm busy setting up and testing our AWS Rest API. We are changing from using our existing bespoke API for the more standards based AWS Rest API, so in order to limit the change over we want to simply use the existing session cookie already set as part of the original login process.

I have created an `Authorizer`, and parse the `Cookie` header to my Lambda function, I can read the cookies, and respond accordingly.

When I test my Lambda Function with the sample Auth Request Authorizer Template, and change the `headerauth1` to `Cookie`, and give it a cookie-like string, it works fine.
When I run a test on my Authorizer it also works fine, and when Deploy and call my API with PostMan it also works fine... correctly responding to the value of the Cookie!

So now the problem is, I have a GET method set on my root resource, the plan is that this responds with text/html of the help documentation if you simply enter the URL into the browser so: https://api.somesite.com/ <- should API documentation if you are logged in, or login page if not.

This is my problem, no matter what I set the cookie to in Chrome, it's always responding with 401 Unauthorised. The, apparently, exact same request via PostMan works fine. I can't see why a PostMan or Chrome request would look any different to the API.

In my response when using Chrome I get:

```
X-Amzn-Errortype: UnauthorizedException
```